# Java Sorting Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Can anyone explain me this sentence please?

> The sorting algorithm is a modified
>   mergesort (in which the merge is
>   omitted if the highest element in the
>   low sublist is less than the lowest
>   element in the high sublist).

Link: [Arrays.sort(Object[] arr)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

I know how Merge works, but I still don't understand well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mergesort recursively merges sorted sublists.  If the current sublists eligible for merging contain no overlapping elements, there's no need to merge them.  The merge operation would be skipped.

Example:

```
List A
1 4 8 9

List B
10 12 14 19
```

There's no need to go through the process of comparing these lists because 9 is the largest element of A and 10 (the first element of B) is larger than the largest element of A.  The result would just be the concatenation of A and B.

All the document is saying is that they take a shortcut if comprehensive processing is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are doing a merge sort and are about to merge your two sorted sublists, `[1, 3, 4]` and `[2, 5, 6]`. Then you must run your merge algorithm to interleave the two halves into the whole `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

```
[1] + [2] + [3, 4] + [5, 6] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But let's say after you've sorted the two halves you have `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`. The highest element in the low sublist (3) is less than the lowest element in the high sublist (4). There's no need to merge the two sublists; you can simply concatenate them together.

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```