# Why is merge sort used by java to sort an array greater than elements 7

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort):

> "In Java, the Arrays.sort() methods use merge sort or a tuned
>   quicksort depending on the datatypes and for implementation efficiency
>   switch to insertion sort when fewer than seven array elements are
>   being sorted"

But why? Both merge sort and quick sort are **O(n log n)**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707190/why-java-arrays-use-two-different-sort-algorithms-for-different-types

Comment: I know Yannis is going to show up and smack me for this, but this probably should be on Programmers.

Comment: And here is an answer of the author of the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154158/why-collections-sort-is-using-merge-sort-insteadof-quicksort

Answer (score 10):

Where the algorithms differ is their *typical case* behavior and this is where insertion sort is one of the worst. On the other hand, for very small collections (n ≈ n<sup>2</sup>) insertion sort's simplicity wins.

Java's algorithm selection rules prefer QuickSort first, and only fall back to something else due to specific restrictions. QuickSort, namely, is an *unstable* sort and thus is only acceptable for the sorting of primitives. For reference types, TimSort is used as of OpenJDK 7 (previously MergeSort).

Comment: Additional note: Insertion sort wins on small collections because it has a lower constant factor, which big-O doesn't record. Note that, for example: `n^2 < 10n` for `n < 10`.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, that's my point. Simplicity means low constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that ad-hoc:

Arrays.java's sort method uses quicksort for arrays of primitives and merge sort for arrays of objects.

[Why does Java's Arrays.sort method use two different sorting algorithms for different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707190/why-java-arrays-use-two-different-sort-algorithms-for-different-types)

Also, according to the docs:

> For example, the algorithm used by sort(Object[]) does not have to be a mergesort, but it does have to be stable.

And another quote from the javadoc:

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be
>   reordered as a result of the sort.
>
> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
>   iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons
>   when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
>   performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
>   randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the
>   implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage
>   requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays
>   to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending
>   order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and
>   descending order in different parts of the the same input array. It is
>   well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate
>   the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python
>   ( TimSort).

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort and mergesort are both O(n log n) in *average* performance. In the worst case, quicksort is O(n^2).

Comment: Their average case is not O(n^2),, its O(nlogn).

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I was focused on the n^2 worst-case, and typed it accidentally for average.

Answer (score 0):

They moved to tuned merge sort because found that statistically for real partially sorted data sets this method may be a little faster than quick sort.

Comment: Java never used MergeSort for primitives, and never used QuickSort for reference types.

Comment: Who is they? References, please.

Comment: That is for `Collections.sort`. Also, it said as fast as. I believe the main reason is still stability, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well Java 7 uses Timsort - a hybrid of Merge and insertion. As a matter of fact it's widely used - android, Octave,python use it too.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort