# Sort algorithm used in primitive array sort in java library

Tags: java-8, java

JDK 7 uses Tim sort for object array. Which algorithm used for primitive array sort ?

Comment: Why not read [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))?

Comment: See also [“Why does Collections.sort use Mergesort but Arrays.sort does not?”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334319/why-does-collections-sort-use-mergesort-but-arrays-sort-does-not/32334651#32334651)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `Dual-Pivot Quicksort` based on this [paper](http://codeblab.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Java uses **Dual-pivot QuickSort** to sort array containing **primitive data**.
And it uses **Insertion sort** if size of array is small (*less than 17*) and if the size of array is greater than 17 it uses **TimSort** (Also know as "variation of merge sort") to sort the array containing the object.

**Tim sort** is also used in **sorting of collections** in java.