# Inbuilt java sorting algorithms for array/linked lists that uses Quicksort

Tags: java, quicksort

I need to bench mark my quick sort algorithm with an inbuilt java sort. Since I am using arraylists and linkedlists, I need an inbuilt java sort that would sort with quick sort.

I have tried Arrays.sort(), but there doesn't seem to work for array and linked lists as arguments.

And also from [Why does Collections.sort use Mergesort but Arrays.sort does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334319/why-does-collections-sort-use-mergesort-but-arrays-sort-does-not)
It is said that the collections.sort() uses merge sort, and that there isn't any inbuilt sort for non primitive types that uses quick sort cause of stability requirements.

So how might I use an inbuilt java algorithm that uses Quicksort to sort arraylist and linkedlists?

Comment: I assume a typo - "doesn't seem to work for array" should be "arraylist", since it certainly does work for arrays!   There does not appear to be any inbuilt java straight-Quicksort implementation, so you'll have to bring in a third-party jar.

Comment: In addition to stability, merge sort on objects may be faster than quick sort, as merge sort does more moves but fewer compares. Java normally implements an array of objects as an array of pointers, increasing the time it takes to do compares, and if the objects are larger than pointers, it's faster to move pointers than to move objects.

Comment: The situation is a bit more complicated. The answer of the linked Q&A has been revised since you asked your question. I suggest reading the new version. But even the old version already told that `Arrays.sort(…)` and `Collections.sort(…)` use the same algorithm (in fact, they use the same code), so it’s not clear why you accepted an answer which just suggests to replace one with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be a way to reverse the test-procedure?
Modify your sorting algorithm to work with an array and use `Arrays.sort()` to match it.
Both classes – `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` – are having a `toArray()` function.
`Arrays.sort()` calls `java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort()` internally.

Comment: But what problem does this solve? TimSort is a variation of MergeSort, in fact, it is exactly the same algorithm used when calling `Collections.sort(…)` or `List.sort(…)`. In case of `ArrayList`, it will just pass its internal array to `Arrays.sort(…)`. So calling `toArray` only adds an unnecessary detour.