# What is the sorting complexity time in the streaming API for the sorted() and thenComparing () methods (sorting by multiple fields (conditions))?

Tags: java-stream, time-complexity, java-11

I have an information that the method **sorted()** in **Stream API** maybe to use merging sort (mergesort).

Then  **time complexity**  for the kind of sort :

**Big Θ** (n (log n) ) - **best**

**Big Ω** (n (log n) ) - **average**

**Big O**  (n (log n) ) -  **worst**

**space complecity** – O (n) - **worst**

And what is the **time complexity** if we use sorting by multiple fields of a custom object, using **then.comparing()** to build a chain of comparisons ?

How would you calculate the time complexity in such a case ?

Comment: That depends on the functions you pass to the comparator factory. Normally, it does not affect the time complexity at all.

Comment: Normally compare function complexity is constant. So time complexity would be the number of compare * compare function complexity.

Comment: @Eklavya, @ Holger: so the time complexity remains -  n (log n) and it doesn't depend from comparator functions?

Comment: @skyho if your compare function complexity remains constant then obviously. But if compare function complexity is like O(n) then sorting complexity will be n*  n (log n)

Comment: Time complexity as a function of *n* depends on the chosen *n* and in turn, on the function’s dependency on *n*. Normally, for sort algorithms, *n* corresponds to the size of the list or array to sort. Then, typical comparison functions do not depend on *n*, hence, have a time complexity of O(1). This implies that the general time complexity of the particular sort algorithm remains, like O(n log n), regardless of the comparator function. An example for a different metric is evaluating the time complexity of sorting a list of very large strings, i.e. *n* strings of *m* characters on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the actual algorithm used in [`Stream.sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()) is intentionally unspecified, there are obvious reasons not to implement another sorting algorithm, but use the existing implementation of [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

The current implementation uses [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), a variation of merge sort that can exploit ranges of pre-sorted elements within the input, with a best case of being entirely linear, when the input is already sorted, which also applies to the possible case that the input is sorted backwards. In these cases, no additional memory is needed. The average case is somewhere between that best case and the unchanged worst case of `O(n log n)`.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32334651/2711488), general statements about the algorithms used in `Arrays.sort` are tricky, because all of them are hybrid sort algorithms and constantly improved.

Normally, a comparison function does not depend on the size of the input (the array or collection to sort), which doesn’t change when using `Comparator.comparing(…).thenComparing(…)`, as more expensive comparison functions only add a constant factor that doesn’t affect the overall time complexity, as long as the comparator still doesn’t depend on the input size.