# Sort String of Characters Using Hashed Array and Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I stumble upon this cool sorting algorithm with `O(n)` time complexity on [GeeksforGeeks - Sort string of characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-string-characters/) and I was trying to refactor the code to use `Java Streams` on the nested for loops instead and collect the result in a string variable but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here's the original code:

```java
// Java program to sort
// a string of characters
public class SortString{
    static final int MAX_CHAR = 26;
 
    // function to print string in sorted order
    static void sortString(String str) {
 
        // Hash array to keep count of characters.
        int letters[] = new int[MAX_CHAR];
 
        // Traverse string and increment
        // count of characters
        for (char x : str.toCharArray()) {
 
            // 'a'-'a' will be 0, 'b'-'a' will be 1,
            // so for location of character in count
            // array we will do str[i]-'a'.
            letters[x - 'a']++;
        }
        
        // HOW TO CONVERT THIS TO JAVA STREAM?  
        // Traverse the hash array and print
        // characters
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < letters[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print((char) (i + 'a'));
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Driver program to test above function
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sortString("geeksforgeeks");
    }
}
// This code is contributed
// by Sinuhe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static final int MAX_CHAR = 26;

static String sortString(String str) {
    int[] letters = new int[MAX_CHAR];
    str.chars().forEach(i -> letters[i - 'a']++);
    return IntStream.range(0, MAX_CHAR)
        .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString(i + 'a').repeat(letters[i]))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sortString("geeksforgeeks"));
}
```

output:

```
eeeefggkkorss
```

Comment: Though this is a good idea, you still need the predefined `letters` array.

Comment: The line `str.chars().forEach(i -> letters[i - 'a']++)` has no advantage over the first `for` loop in the original solution and violates guidelines of the [*Stream API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) in regard to side-effects. When there are other alternatives (which the case here), you should not resort to changing the state of objects outside the stream via side-effects.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the loop of the original solution uses `toCharArray()` which is avoided here. So there is a slight advantage.

Comment: @Holger Agree, generating char array from the string is redundant. Approach with traditional index based loop would be better `for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) letters[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko on the other hand, you can just use `char[] array = str.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(array); System.out.println(array);` the built-in method will fall back to counting sort for large arrays anyway.

Comment: @Holger *will fall back to **counting sort** for large arrays* - that a new observation for me, thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the implementation notes about the used algorithms are misleading and demonstrate why authors should be avoid mentioning such implementation details in the documentation, as I already wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32334651/2711488)

Answer (score 2):

We can sort the given string, which is expected to contain only lower case English letters, in **O(n)** time with streams only (*without using a **precalculated array***) by making use of the `LinkedHashMap`, which would be used internally inside the *collector*.

We can create a *custom collector* which will accumulate stream elements into a `LinkedHashMap` by using static method `Collector.of()`. After processing the whole string, a `LinkedHashMap` will contain a frequency of every lower case English letter in the given string and *finisher function* of the *collector* will turn this map into the resulting string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aewwawaeaea";

    String result = str.chars()
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')
                .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (map, next) -> map.put(next, 0), LinkedHashMap::putAll),
            (LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map, Integer next) -> map.merge(next, 1, Integer::sum),
            (left, right) -> {
                right.forEach((k, v) -> left.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
                return left;
            },
            map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> Character.toString(entry.getKey()).repeat(entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
        ));
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
aaaaaeeewww
```

As it has been suggested by *@Holger* in the [*comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72933808/sort-string-of-characters-using-hashed-array-and-java-8-streams/72936292#comment128824522_72933963), we can build a *collector* on based on the `int` array of `26` elements.

The *collector* is more concise and performant than the previous one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aewwawaeaea";
    String result = str.chars()
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> new int['z' - 'a' + 1],
            (int[] arr, Integer next) -> arr[next - 'a']++,
            (left, right) -> {
                Arrays.setAll(left, i -> left[i] + right[i]);
                return left;
            },
            arr -> IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString(i + 'a').repeat(arr[i]))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
        ));
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
aaaaaeeewww
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream` to convert the nested loop to a stream, like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ABC{
  static final int MAX_CHAR = 26;
  static void sortString(String str) {
    int letters[] = new int[MAX_CHAR];
    for (char x : str.toCharArray()) {
      letters[x - 'a']++;
    }
    IntStream.range(0, letters.length).forEach(i -> {
      IntStream.range(0, letters[i]).forEach(ch -> {
        System.out.print((char) (i + 'a'));
      });
    });
  }

  // Driver program to test above function
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sortString("geeksforgeeks");
  }
}
```

Working [link](https://onlinegdb.com/oWybA3Z1v).

Comment: Though the solution is legit, replacing `for` with `IntStream` is still iterative and doesn't comply with the spirit of declarative programming through [tag:java-stream].

Comment: I agree with you on that part.

Answer (score 1):

The best snippet that doesn't require precalculated array I am able to produce is this:

```java
final String result = str.chars()
    .boxed()
    .collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                ch -> ch - 'a',
                TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.counting()),
            map -> map.entrySet().stream().collect(
                StringBuilder::new,
                (sb, e) -> sb.append(Character.toString(e.getKey() + 'a')
                                              .repeat(e.getValue().intValue())),
                StringBuilder::append)
        )
    ).toString();
```

- The inner `groupingBy` groups the characters to the position in an alphabet (key) and the count (value). The keys for the count is 0 are omitted (they don't get into the map at all). The output after this part looks like this:

  > ```
  > {4=4, 5=1, 6=2, 10=2, 14=1, 17=1, 18=2}
  > ```

  Note I used `TreeMap` to keep the characters sorted.
- The `collectingAndThen` wraps the `Map<Integer, Long>` and using a mutable reduction in another stream to resull in `StringBuilder` with the correct position and amount of the characters (note I use `String#repeat` as of Java 11 that can be backported or easily substituted by a custom/utility method).

Conclusion:

- Is this solution in the declarative spirit of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream)? **Yes, it is**.
- Is this solution better? **Nope.** It is not even more readable or nice piece of code to look at. It is ok for sake of getting more familiar with streams.
- Is this solution more efficient? **Nope, it is not `0(n)` anymore.** Remember it is not always possible to represent iterative `for` loop(s) directly by a declarative approach using Stream API and achieve the same performance.

Comment: It is not `O(n)`.

Comment: I didn't declare the solution is `O(n)` (I explicitly add this info for sure). The solution is, though, in the declarative spirit of Stream API.

Comment: @英語は苦手 Well, technically this solution has a time complexity of `O(n)`, because the map will contain at most `26` entries and therefore adding new entry into the map (or updating existing entry) in the worst case scenario would be proportional to `log(26)` which should be considered `O(1)`, **not** `O(log n)`.  Which gives the overall time complexity of `O(n)`. We can lower the cost of updating the entries by making use of `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko when you use a `LinkedHashMap`, the result will not be sorted anymore. What you could do, is use an array instead of a map inside the collector, just like with the original approach.

Comment: @Holger I meant a `LinkedHashMap` prepopulated with `26` entries, all having initial `0` values. That would guarantee that the result would be sorted.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko but the idea was not to have a prepopulated data structure. As said, if you go that route, a plain array would be even simpler and more efficient. A collector around an array is not worse than a collector around a map.

Comment: @Holger *plain array would be even simpler and more efficient* - Agree.

Answer (score 1):

For example (Java 11+):

```
String foo(String s) {
    return s.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(ignore -> 1)),
            integerLongMap -> IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')
                    .mapToObj(value -> Character.toString(value).repeat(integerLongMap.getOrDefault(value, 0)))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining())
    ));
}


System.out.println(foo("bbccdefbbaa"));  // aabbbbccdef
System.out.println(foo("geeksforgeeks"));  // eeeefggkkorss
```

But it's harder to read than iterative version, imho.